# VBA Cellsのドットの後ろの入力で入力候補が出ません。

Tags: vba

お世話になっております。
VBAの　Cells(....).Selectを入力する際に、.の後ろのSelectが入力候補がでず、エラーになります。
Rangeなどではそのような事は起きません。
なぜでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 具体的なコードを提示できませんか？

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sf-rBeuTF8kBTIcUHRrWnUpWM3_G4Rka/view?usp=share_link

Comment: 上記の画像のように、エラーは生じませんが、入力候補が出る場合と出ない場合が生じております。